# How to set maximum JPanel width but to stay height free to grow?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

How to set maximum JPanel width but to stay height free to grow ? ( I cannot use prefferedSize for strange reason ).

Comment: I really don't understand your last 3 posts, about similair issue, 1/ http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html 2/ and its time to post code where you show your strange issue with setPrefferedSize 3/ for some LayoutManager works as chaims

Comment: Though i cannot understand your question completely but i have posted an answer

Answer (score 2):

Use LayoutManagers.  `BoxLayout`, `GridBagLayout`, or some other layout will allow you to define a single direction of growth for a panel.

Comment: hmm ... probably misunderstanding what you are trying to say, but: afaik, BoxLayout as such doesn't allow to specify "direction of growth" (whatever that is ;-) Could you elaborate a bit? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is use MigLayout http://www.miglayout.com/
There you can easily override minimal:prefered:maximal size. And mainly it works properly.